# Pull Access accdb query into Excel 2007 error 3265

Tags: sql, database, excel, vba

newbie here. Found the following code on the internet. It has been around for years. I have customized it for my application. Updated reference to MS Office 12.0 access data base engine library. I continually get the 3265 error at the .Parameters line. The query runs fine inside Access and I have been able to pull in a non-parameter query using this code. Have checked spelling ok. The "Rez ID" in the parameter is an alias. The actual heading is AIANHH. Have tried all combinations of the alias and actual heading but still get 3265 at .Parameter
 Don't want to do a push because of specific formatting in Excel. Trying to avoid MS Query because I already have everything working ok in Access. I have numerous queries and don't want to start over with MS Query.The only difference I have noticed is that in Access, the criteria is formatted as: ["Rez ID"] Have tried moving the [] and "" around with no success. Seems like I'm so close to getting this to work but can't get over the hump. Any help would be appreciated.

```vb
Sub RunParameterQuery()  
'Step 1: Declare your variables  
Dim MyDatabase As DAO.Database  
Dim MyQueryDef As DAO.QueryDef  
Dim MyRecordset As DAO.Recordset  
Dim i As Integer  
'Step 2: Identify the database and query  
Set MyDatabase = DBEngine.OpenDatabase _  
("C:\Users\Phil\Documents\Indians\Population & Employment\2010 Population\Census_Data_Set\MS2007_Files\2010_AIANSF_a_1_2_6_8_9_10.accdb")  
Set MyQueryDef = MyDatabase.QueryDefs("Reservation_TTRACT")  
'Step 3: Define the Parameters  
With MyQueryDef  
.Parameters("[Rez ID]") = Range("D3").Value  
'.Parameters("[CHARITER]") = Range("D4").Value  
End With  
'Step 4: Open the query  
Set MyRecordset = MyQueryDef.OpenRecordset  
'Step 5: Clear previous contents  
Sheets("Sheet1").Select  
ActiveSheet.Range("A6:K10000").ClearContents  
'Step 6: Copy the recordset to Excel  
ActiveSheet.Range("A7").CopyFromRecordset MyRecordset  
'Step 7: Add column heading names to the spreadsheet  
For i = 1 To MyRecordset.Fields.Count  
ActiveSheet.Cells(6, i).Value = MyRecordset.Fields(i - 1).Name  
Next I  
MsgBox "Your Query has been Run"  
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to put a parameter in a where statement?  What is your actual query written out?

Comment: The query is in Access and it works fine in Access  SELECT DISTINCT aiangeo.SUMLEV, AIANSF_Segment_031.CHARITER, aiangeo.AIANHH, aiangeo.TTRACT, AIANSF_Segment_031.PCT0030001, AIANSF_Segment_031.PCT0040001, AIANSF_Segment_031.PCT0030002, AIANSF_Segment_031.PCT0040002, AIANSF_Segment_031.PCT0030106, AIANSF_Segment_031.PCT0040003
FROM (AIANSF_Segment_031 INNER JOIN aiangeo ON AIANSF_Segment_031.LOGRECNO = aiangeo.LOGRECNO) INNER JOIN AIANSF_Segment_01 ON aiangeo.LOGRECNO = AIANSF_Segment_01.LOGRECNO
WHERE (((aiangeo.SUMLEV)="250") AND ((aiangeo.AIANHH)=["Rez ID"]));

Comment: I'm new to this forum so still trying to figure out the syntax  I'm just trying to call the Query from Excel with MyQueryDef

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. I had to add a Like statement to the Access Query. I have no Idea why but everything is working now.